# Attempted import error: 'Typography' is not exported from 'antd'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Antd failing to compile on specific Typographies and compiling perfectly on the others.

This is the list of what I have included on my antd-react project:

```js
import {
  Input,
  Col,
  Row,
  Select,
  InputNumber,
  AutoComplete,
  Cascader,
  Option,
  Menu,
  Icon,
  Popover,
  Button,
  Form,
  Checkbox,
  InputGroup,
  DatePicker
} from "antd";
```

In this case, every Typography works expect `Option` which fails to compile.

I have already tried re-installing the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such component `Option` if you mean `Select.Option` in this case you need to:

```js
import { Select } from 'antd';

const { Option } = Select;
```

Use the [search bar](https://ant.design/components/select/#Option-props) to look for `Option` and you will notice it refers to `Select`.

You can [check all the available components](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) on the left sidebar.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can also use option without destructuring `Select` by
`import { Select } from 'antd';`
`...<Select.Option ...>`
```